# Fluent NHibernate Upgrade to NH3.0 alpha

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Hy
We want to use the latest alpha version of NHibernate. Unfortunately the latest fluent nhibernate release is built for 2.1 GA. When do you plan to upgrade to latest NH? Is there a source tree which I can fork to build the latest version from?

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it using NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to download their latest binaries from Git [here](http://fluentnhibernate.org/downloads) and build against NH3 assemblies (it includes a project file where you would just need to update references from 2.1 to 3).. but probably they already did that in "Unstable/future binaries".

Answer (score 1):

Get the latest source code for fluent nhibernate and change the references from 2.1.2 to 3.0 and recompile the fluent nhibernate code.

Comment: I did that for NH 3.1 See : https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/pull/14

Answer (score 1):

You also can put AssemblyRedirect and use Fluent with latest Nhibernate. Fluent generates XML mappings, so everything should be fine.